# Strange Problem when Handling xml using DOM ,PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I want to handle a xml like this:

```
<GeocodeResponse> 
 <status>OK</status> 
 <result> 
  <type>street_address</type> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>Beijing</long_name> 
   <short_name>Beijing</short_name> 
   <type>locality</type> 
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component> 
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>Beijing</long_name> 
   <short_name>Beijing</short_name> 
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component>  
 </result> 
</GeocodeResponse>
```

what I wanna do is loop the node under < address_component >

when using this :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($contents);

$addresses=$doc->getElementsByTagName("address_component");

foreach($addresses as $address){

    $nodes = $address->$childNodes; //error arise here

    for($i=0;$i<count($nodes);$i++){
        //do work
    }

}
```

It always show :

```
    Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\read.php on line

$nodes = $address->$childNodes;
```

while it works fine with the code below :

```
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($contents);

        $addresses=$doc->getElementsByTagName("address_component");
        for($k=0;$k<$addresses->length;$k++){
        $type_elements = $addresses->item($k)->getElementsByTagName('type');

            //do work        
        }
```

I can not see the difference between these two method,in the first example,when I do the 'foreach' ,the $address I get is a single  < address_component > element like this:

```
  <address_component> 
   <long_name>Beijing</long_name> 
   <short_name>Beijing</short_name> 
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type> 
  </address_component>
```

right?

and of course it has $childNodes like < long_name >,< short_name >,etc.

but why I get empty property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to access a property, it should be `childNodes` without the `$`

```
$nodes = $address->childNodes;
```

When you put the `$` in front, PHP will try to evaluate it as a [variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

<sub>*On a sidenote, you seem to have `error_reporting` disabled or set too low, otherwise you would have seen the notice telling you `Notice: Undefined variable: childNodes`. You should set `error_reporting(-1)` on development machines to enable all errors.*</sub>